# Django Allauth Error: NoReverseMatch at /accounts/facebook/login/token/

Tags: django, django-allauth

When trying to login using the fb js_sdk I receive the below error. However using oauth2 works fine when I switch back to using it. Am I missing some configuration somewhere?

```
Internal Server Error: /accounts/facebook/login/token/

NoReverseMatch at /accounts/facebook/login/token/
Reverse for '' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'request': <WSGIRequest: POST '/accounts/facebook/login/token/'>}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried:
```

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
        'allauth',
        'allauth.account',
        'allauth.socialaccount',
        'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',
        'debug_toolbar',
]

    MIDDLEWARE = [
        'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    ]

    TEMPLATES = [
        {
            'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
            'DIRS': [ BASE_DIR + '/main/templates/allauth/',],
            'APP_DIRS': True,
            'OPTIONS': {
                'context_processors': [
                    'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                    'django.template.context_processors.request',
                    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                    'main.context_processors.get_search_query'
                ],
            },
        },
    ]


    AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
        # Needed to login by username in Django admin, regardless of `allauth`
        'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
        # `allauth` specific authentication methods, such as login by e-mail
        'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
    )


    # ALLAUTH
    ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = "username_email"
    ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
    ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = "optional"
    ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = True
    ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS = 'main.forms.SignupForm'
    ACCOUNT_PRESERVE_USERNAME_CASING = True
    ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATED_LOGIN_REDIRECTS = True
    ACCOUNT_SESSION_REMEMBER = True
  SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
        'facebook': {
            'METHOD': 'js_sdk',
            'SCOPE': ['email', 'public_profile'],
            'AUTH_PARAMS': {'auth_type': 'reauthenticate'},
            'FIELDS': [
                'id',
                'email',
                'name',
                'first_name',
                'last_name',
                'verified',
                'locale',
                'timezone',
                'link',
                'gender',
                'updated_time',
            ],
            'EXCHANGE_TOKEN': True,
            'VERIFIED_EMAIL': False,
            'VERSION': 'v2.4',
        }
    }
```

login.html

```
{% extends "bases/bootstrap-auth.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% load i18n %}
{% load bootstrap3 %}
{% load account socialaccount %}
{% block head %}<meta name="robots" content="noindex">{% endblock %}

{% block extra_title %}{% trans "Log In" %}{% endblock %}
{% block inner-content %}
{% providers_media_js %}
{% get_providers as socialaccount_providers %}

    <div class="text-center">
<h1 class="text-center">Log In</h1>
          <small>Don't have an account? <a href="{% url 'account_signup' %}">Signup, it's free!</a></small>

    </div><hr>

<div class="row">


  <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <a title="{{provider.name}}" href="{% provider_login_url "facebook" method="js_sdk" %}"
     class="btn btn-block btn-social btn-facebook">
    <span class="fa fa-facebook"></span> Login with Facebook
  </a>

 <div class="strike">
   <span>or</span>
</div>
  </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}

{% block head_css %}
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap-social.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
{% endblock %}
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    url(r'^accounts/profile/$', main.views.account_profile, name='account_profile'),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you have correct login redirect URL setup in settings.py file
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "/"

Comment: This solved my issue. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the [correct code](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#django) to your `urls.py`?

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    ...
]
```

Comment: Hi sorry have updated my question with `urls.py` which looks correct

Comment: What line is throwing the error? Can you provide the entire stack trace? It seems like `reverse` is receiving `''` as a parameter, which is obviously incorrect (basically asking for a URL by name and providing no name).

Comment: Ah brilliant thank you it was something much further up the stack trace which was causing the issue, `user_logged_in` signal I implemented had a bug which was trying to do a empty redirect!